# Sum() the output of a function in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to achieve a sum of all orders of a cuctomer.
I have created an SQL function to calculate the amount of a given order:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION invoices.orderAmount(quantity INT, price INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE orderTotal INT;
  SET orderTotal = quantity * price;
  RETURN orderTotal;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

while trying to save this function, i get this error:
[image: error image]
now I want to get all the sums of all customer's orders with a command like:

$totalOrderQuery =" SELECT price, quantity, sum(invoices.orderAmount(price,quantity)) AS CustomersTotalBill FROM `invoices` WHERE  purchaseId=$purchaseId AND status='ordered' AND OrderCancel='NO'";

Comment: and what was the problem? Other than you reversed the parameters to your function

Comment: it produces errors

Comment: your php code is **vulnerable** to **sql inection** so use **prepared statements with paramenerts**

Comment: then write the complete error message

Comment: You are also missing the ) on your `sum`

Comment: Can you open your MySQL error log file and share the MySQL error from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The use of a stored function seems overkill for such a simple operation.
2. You reversed the parameters in the call to your function
3. You are missing a closing parenthesis in your SELECT statement
4. The `price` and `quantity` columns in your SELECT are meaningless because the SUM will cause the results to be grouped.
5. You didn't specify a "GROUP BY" so all results will be in one row. Use GROUP BY to group by customer id

You should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(invoices.orderAmount(quantity,price)) AS CustomersTotalBill FROM invoices WHERE  purchaseId=:PurchaseID AND status='ordered' AND OrderCancel='NO'
GROUP BY invoices.customerid
```

(assuming you have a `customerid` column to identify the customer)

EDIT: original suggestion removed the function call and didn't use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT SUM(price * quantity) AS CustomersTotalBill FROM invoices WHERE  purchaseId=:PurchaseID AND status='ordered' AND OrderCancel='NO'
```

Use a prepared statement to provide the value to PurchaseID.
If using PDO:

```
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($QUERY);

 $stmt->execute([ 'PurchaseID' => $purchaseId ]);
```

Comment: I edited to better answer the question of how to use the function, and to address the updated question regarding for "each customer"

Answer (score 0):

Your error message tells you what is wrong

change the  Function to

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION invoices.orderAmount(quantity INT, price INT) RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE orderTotal INT;
  SET orderTotal = quantity * price;
  RETURN orderTotal;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But use only **prepared statements with parameters** in your php code. see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)